# In Kinvey after login icon are found in different colors & image (top right corner side on web page like red, green)

Tags: authentication, icons, kinvey

In Kinvey.com created a user with email id & password.

After login with the above credential in top right corner the icons are found in different colors & image.

Can you please answer me the meaning of these different colour as well as images?

Due to this differentiation, I am not able to get active user. So please let me know how to get red colour icon into green that is in active state.

Awaiting your answer ASAP.

Thanks,
Sunita

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer at Kinvey, and that's nothing to worry about.  That little icon is a `gravatar`, which is just a custom icon used to represent you!  Check out [gravatar.com's website](http://en.gravatar.com/) which might help explain it better.

It's actually very similar to that symbol next to your name here-- your's is a purple geometric shape with triangles pointing outwards and 4 circles in the center, mine is blue and angled.

So don't worry about that, the colors and images don't actually mean anything and are just a unique image per user.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply... :)

Also I am able to get Active user.

In this case to get Active user, we need to 'sign in' user at least one time via code & then we can always ping them to get active user.